# Confused by the way to construct an abstract contract

Tags: solidity

Confused by an example of the [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/contracts.html#inheritance)

Codes like below

```
// These abstract contracts are only provided to make the
// interface known to the compiler. Note the function
// without body. If a contract does not implement all
// functions it can only be used as an interface.
abstract contract Config {
   function lookup(uint id) public virtual returns (address adr);
}

// Multiple inheritance is possible. Note that `owned` is
// also a base class of `Destructible`, yet there is only a single
// instance of `owned` (as for virtual inheritance in C++).
contract Named is Owned, Destructible {
   constructor(bytes32 name) {
       Config config = Config(0xD5f9D8D94886E70b06E474c3fB14Fd43E2f23970);
       NameReg(config.lookup(1)).register(name);
   }
....
```

What I don't get is how can construct a `Config` contract instance like that ?

```
Config config = Config(0xD5f9D8D94886E70b06E474c3fB14Fd43E2f23970);
```

`Config` is an abstract contract without defining a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config is an instance of Config contract. Normally, you dont need to know the address of the Config contract because you can deploy with Named.

You can use Config lookup() function if you declare like:

```
contract Named is Config, Owned, Destructible { ...
```

In your example, Config contract was deployed first and is working in the blockchain.
The Config contract of your example is an Interface that let Named use the real Config contract called with the deployment contract address

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get it now. It seems `Config(existed_address)` means get a contract instance from the address `existed_address`where was depolyed the contract already.